# Let $l$ be the minimum value of $2(y-2)^2 +4(x -7)^2 +(y+4)^2$. Find $[2018/l]$ where $[\cdot]$ is the greatest integer function.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

> $l$ is equal to the minimum value of the expression $2(y-2)^2 + 4(x -7)^2 + (y+4)^2$. Find $[2018/l]$ where $[\cdot]$ denotes the greatest integer function.

Here is my approach:

In order to obtain the minimum value of the expression, one of the terms has to be zero, so let $x=7$ and $y=2$. We get $(2+4)^2=36$ and $[2018/36]=56$.

Is this answer right?

Comment: Here is a counterexample to your claim:  Find the minimum of $(y-2)^2+(y+2)^2$.  According to your claim you suggest setting $y$ so that one of these terms is zero, e.g. the first, which would happen at $y=2$, giving a result of $(2-2)^2+(2+2)^2=0^2+4^2=16$, but for my example $y=0$ happens to give a smaller result: $(2-0)^2+(2+0)^2=2^2+2^2=8<16$.  In general, finding minimums and maximums can be accomplished by using differential calculus (*or results from calculus that are taught early*).

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: For the special case of parabolas, if written in the form $f(x)=a(x-h)^2+k$, the maximum/minimum (*max if $a>0$ and min if $a<0$*) occurs at the point $f(h)=k$.  For parabolas written in general form $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ it occurs at $f(\frac{-b}{2a})$.  This is sometimes taught well before derivatives.

Comment: Hint: $\;2(y-2)^2 + (y+4)^2 = 3 y^2 + 24\,$.

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

Nope, that is not the right way.

Letting $x=7$ is a good move.

now, let's focus on the $y$ terms. To minimize

$$2(y-2)^2+(y+4)^2$$

You can differentiate the function with respect to $y$ and equate it to zero to solve for the $y$ corresponding to the minimum value.

Note that the function is convex hence there is a minimum.